# Voltages for motors

Tags: voltage, dc-motor

I was planning on buying a DC electrical motor of about 1/2 hp 3000 rpm when I noticed its nominal voltage was 24 Volts. Maximum torque is at something like 1.8 newton-meters.

My question is whether a 90 Volt DC motor with the same specifications would act differently.

Comment: What are the torques of the motors?

Comment: Well I have only found the 24v one and the maximum torque is at something like 1.8 newton-meters. Thanks for the quick answer :)

Comment: I you know of a website where i could buy 90v motors could you please tell me the name otherwise I will look thanks again :)

Comment: On the electrical side, the motors would act quite differently. On the mechanical side, they could be quite similar--check the RPM & Torque characteristics.